# Check the flash light status

Tags: android, kotlin

How to check flash light is enabled or not in kotlin language.(For API 33)

**I tried this.``**

```
private fun isFlashLightEnabled(context: Context): Boolean {
        val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
        try {
            val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList[0]
            val torchStatus = cameraManager.getTorchMode(cameraId)
            return torchStatus == "on"
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return false

    }`
```

But i got this "Unresolved reference: getTorchMode".

Comment: Well it shows 'Unresolved reference: getTorchMode' because there is no such method listed in the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager

There is only setTorchMode() and it does not return anything